# Virtual Delete in EntityFramework 5.0

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

My Problem is..

I will ask my user, whether he want to delete record or not. If he says yes,

I am not going to actually delete the row from table, but will update the Deleted column of my table with true. But before doing this, I want to check the foreign key constraint as we do in Delete row case, means if the value is used by some other table. I should say my user that this row is used by other table so cannot delete?

Is there any idea how can I do this.

Currenly I doing this to delete..

```
public bool Delete(dynamic entity)
{
    try
    {
        //here I want to check, whether this is being used by some other table or not. Foreign key constaint
        entity.Deleted = true;
        this.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch { return false; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer applies to entity framework 5.0 and Code First.
The solution requires two parts. First, each of your data classes must implement an interface that exposes a 'Deleted' property (let's call it IVirtualDelete).

```
public interface IVirtualDelete{
  bool Deleted {get; set;}
}
```

Second, you need to override the SaveChanges method in your DBContext.

When SaveChanges is called, look at the context.ChangeTracker.Entities() for those which have a state of System.Data.EntityState.Deleted and the Entity implements your IVirtualDelete interface. Set Deleted on the object, and change the entity state to Modified.

```
public override int SaveChanges() {
  foreach (var item in this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x=> x.EntityState == EntityState.Deleted)){
    var entity = item.Entity as IVirtualDelete;
    if(entity != null){
      entity.Deleted = true;
      item.EntityState = EntityState.Modified;
    }
  }
  return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And that is "about it". EF has no method to override a delete into an update, and at the end it can be argued that this is not good because the mechanism may vary (timestamp for deleted etc.). So, what you do is what People do in this case.

Comment: I am not deleting actually, but will just update a column. Before that I want to check

Answer (score 0):

You can try change primary key value for your entity and save.

If any child record exist - you will receive some kind of cascade update error and return false.

If update succeed - you have no child records, you can change primary key value back to original, set Deleted = true and re-save.

Of course, this doesn't apply if you have identity as primary key or have child tables with 'delete cascade' user-visible-scenario.